# SQL Union for multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to show the results of both tables on the same querys, the tables are identical but one stores historic information and the other one has today's info (online), my tables look something like this.

Historic Table: TBL1

```
T_ID            Resolve             Date
----------      ------------        ------------
AD_1234         GOOD                12/18/16
VF_4569         BAD                 12/19/16
RT_5436         GOOD                12/17/16
```

Online Table: TBL2

```
T_ID            Resolve             Date
----------      ------------        ------------
AR_2334         BAD                 12/20/16
FT_1362         BAD                 12/20/16
GH_5676         GOOD                12/20/16
```

Expected Result: TBL3

```
T_ID            Resolve             Date
----------      ------------        ------------
AD_1234         GOOD                12/18/16
VF_4569         BAD                 12/19/16
RT_5436         GOOD                12/17/16
AR_2334         BAD                 12/20/16
FT_1362         BAD                 12/20/16
GH_5676         GOOD                12/20/16
```

Can't create new tables, views or any kind of objects it has to be done by query.

I Keep getting duplicate records and I know I dont have the same data on either table.

```
select o.transaction_id, o.ts_0002
from data_headers1 o
where 
virtual_table_id = '5237260000000002621'
union all
select h.transaction_id, h.ts_0002
from data_headers1_hist h
where virtual_table_id = '5237260000000002621'
 and TO_CHAR(h.ts_0002, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '2016/12/01 00:00:00'
 and TO_CHAR(h.ts_0002, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') <= '2016/12/30 23:59:59';
```

Comment: you know you have to use `union`..so have you tried it?

Comment: Please at least make an attempt and post your code.

Comment: **UNION ALL** for god sake

Comment: You are not going to learn anything from this requested result format. Can you use a better sample to demonstrate what you are looking for?

Comment: I've tried the Union ALL but it gives me duplicate records, and I know for a fact that both tables dont have the same data. Here is my code....

Comment: Can the same transaction_id appear in both tables? more than once in the same table?

Comment: No, Im sure they dont have the same Id on both tables

Comment: And in the same table?

Comment: No, they are actually Primary keys on both tables, that's why im so confused

Comment: Right at the end of your query, add `group by transaction_id, ts_002 having count(*) > 1`. This will show which rows are duplicates. Then hunt them down in the two tables - see if they are, in fact, duplicates in one of the tables, or if they are unique in each table but they appear in both tables. Then you'll have to see why a PK constraint is violated (perhaps it is not ENABLED?) or why you may have overlaps between the tables, etc. Try to solve this one small step at a time.

Comment: @Mathguy Thank you! It seems that a constraint was not enabled on the historic table, had to change those records and and a simple union all worked for the result i was looking for... One for the noob book - "Do not trust the user".

Comment: @Zombraz - lol, that is the TITLE of the noob book! As they say, "computers are too dumb to lie." Whenever there is a discrepancy between what the user says and what the computer says, the prime suspect is always the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime:

You'll have to know the source (TBL1/TBL2) for your data

```
           select 1 as tab,T_ID,Resolve,"Date" from TBL1 t
union all  select 2       ,T_ID,Resolve,"Date" from TBL2 t
```

---

P.s.

Change the condition on h.ts_0002
1. If there are partitions / indexes on h.ts_0002, you are preventing them from being used.
2. Converting h.ts_0002 of all rows to char is a waste of resources.

```
    h.ts_0002 >= timestamp '2016-12-01 00:00:00' 
and h.ts_0002 <  timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
```

---

P.s. 2

```
select      transaction_id
           ,count(*)                            as total
           ,count(case tab when 1 then 1 end)   as tab1
           ,count(case tab when 2 then 1 end)   as tab2

from       (select      1 as tab
                       ,o.transaction_id 
            from        data_headers1 o
            where       virtual_table_id = '5237260000000002621'

            union all

            select      2
                       ,h.transaction_id
            from        data_headers1_hist h
            where       virtual_table_id = '5237260000000002621'
                    and h.ts_0002 >= timestamp '2016-12-01 00:00:00' 
                    and h.ts_0002 <  timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
            )

group by    transaction_id    

having      count(*) > 1

order by    transaction_id
;
```

Comment: Since things do not adds up, please run the query in **P.s. 2** to verify

Comment: Thank you! Let me give it a try.

Comment: Now it doesnt show me any information, I tried it with the single UNION and it worked, but it took around 45 mins to get 34k records.

Comment: @Zombraz - that doesn't make sense - why did you try with UNION when you want to understand duplicates? UNION removes duplicates so running Dudu's diagnostic query with UNION instead of UNION ALL is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a declarative language, simply it means you want the union of some data, just use the term UNION (SQL Server example):

```
SELECT T_ID, Resolve, Date From Tbl1 
UNION 
SELECT T_ID, Resolve, Date From Tbl2
```

*the query is not tested.

**Note**: If you need to show the duplicated results you can replace UNION with UNION ALL.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz why union all, you can use union or union all based on the requirements

Comment: `as tbl3` also isn't valid (at least in Oracle).

Comment: @AlexPoole Please notice the part: the query is not tested; and the code is valid AFIK in SQL Server

Comment: If I only use union the quer takes way too long to process.

Comment: @Zombraz are you using sql server?

Comment: @Mok no, Im using Oracle 11g

Comment: @Mok,Thank you! I'll take a look at it